# Integral Inequality related to Integrand Inequality

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory, lebesgue-integral

Maybe this is an obvious question but consider density functions $p(x) = \frac{d\mathbb{P}}{d\lambda}(x), q(x) = \frac{d\mathbb{Q}}{d\lambda}(x)$ of some probability measures $\mathbb{P}, \mathbb{Q}$ on some measurable space $(\Omega, \mathcal{B}(\Omega))$. Assuming that $\mathbb{P}(B) \leq \mathbb{Q}(B)$ for all $B \in \mathcal{B}(\Omega)$, this implies that

$\int\limits_B p(x) d\lambda(x) = \mathbb{P}(B) \leq \mathbb{Q}(B) = \int\limits_B q(x) d\lambda(x)$ for all $B \in \mathcal{B}(\Omega)$.

Does that imply that $p(x) \leq q(x)$ $\lambda$-almost everywhere ?

I feel like it should but I did not find a theorem or proof of this yet...

Comment: A probability density should integrate to 1. Are you allowing Dirac deltas? Because if not, then if Q integrates to 1 and P is always less than Q then P can't integrate to 1.

Comment: Ok let me phrase it differently, because as you are obviously right, if $\mathbb{P} \leq \mathbb{Q}$ on all of $\mathcal{B}(\Omega)$, then there must hold $\mathbb{P} = \mathbb{Q}$. If, however, there should hold $\mathbb{P} \leq \mathbb{Q}$ only on part of the sigma algebra, namely on $\{A \in \mathcal{B}(\Omega): A \subset supp(\mathbb{Q})\}$ (then on the complement $0 = \mathbb{Q} \leq \mathbb{P}$), does that imply that $p(x) \leq q(x)$ for $x \in supp(\mathbb{Q})$ ?
On the other hand, would then $q(x) \leq p(x)$ for $x \in supp(\mathbb{Q})^c$ ?